# How to display name instead of id

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have two tables: `albums` and `categories`.

I am displaying albums details with a `foreach` loop that includes  `category_id` in my index page.

I want to display `category_name` instead of `category id`.

I am using Laravel

Controller code..

```
public function index() {
    $albums = Album::all();
    $categories = DB::table('albums')
        ->join('categories','albums.category_id','=','categories.id')
        ->select('*')->get();

    return view('admin.profile.index',compact('albums','categories'));
}
```

View code:

```
@foreach($albums as $album)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$album->album_name}}</td>
    <td>I want to diplay category_name here</td>
    <td>{{$album->created_at}}</td>
    <td>
      <input type="image" src="images/icn_edit.png" title="Edit">
      <input type="image" src="images/icn_trash.png" title="Trash">
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

I want to display the `category_name` within the second `<td>` tag.

Comment: You're passing in both `albums` and `categories` to the view. That seems redundant. You're already joining the 2 in the query. From the looks of things you only need to pass the `categories` to the view and loop over thru that. Also don't do `select *`, just take what you need.

Comment: How should I proceed If i will not pass the both then How I will get the Category_name within he 2nd <td> tag. please suggest any other way

Comment: You're doing a basic join on 2 tables, you're getting all the information you need. var_dump the categories and see what you get.

Answer (score 3):

First in your model, create relationship, follow out this steps :-

Albums.php

```
public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'id');
    }
```

Categories.php

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Album');
    }
```

controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $albums = Album::all();

        return View::make('admin.profile.index', compact('albums'));
    }
```

view

```
 @foreach($albums as $album)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $album->album_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $album->category->title }}</td>
        <td>{{ $album->created_at }}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Add you column selection in your controller like:

```
public function index()
    {
     $albums = Album::all();

$categories = DB::table('albums')
    ->join('categories','albums.category_id','=','categories.id')
    ->select('*,categories.category_name as cat_name')->get();
return view('admin.profile.index',compact('albums','categories'));

   }
```

View Code:

```
  @foreach($albums as $album)
            <tr>

                <td>{{$album->album_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$album->cat_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$album->created_at}}</td>
                <td><input type="image" src="images/icn_edit.png" title="Edit"><input type="image" src="images/icn_trash.png" title="Trash">           </td>
            </tr>
                @endforeach
```